# Can we send a request object or keyword argument to modelformset_factory in django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I have the following view

```
def application(request, uuid):
    application = get_object_or_404(LoanApplication, uuid=uuid)

    partners = FirmPartner.objects.filter(application=application)
    PartnerFormset = modelformset_factory(FirmPartner, form=FirmPartnerForm, can_delete=True, extra=1)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        .........
        ..........
```

But i want to make some fields in FirmPartnerForm required dynamically inside **init** method of form by using some values from request or keyword argument that we passed in like `modelformset_factory(......application=application)` ?

So is it possible to send request object or any keyword argument to modelformset_factory ? as below

```
modelformset_factory(FirmPartner, form=FirmPartnerForm, can_delete=True, extra=1, request=request, application=application) ?
```

***Edit***

Now i upgraded to django 1.9.9 and below is my code

```
from .forms import FirmPartnerForm

PartnerFormset = modelformset_factory(FirmPartner, form=FirmPartnerForm, can_delete=True, extra=1,
                       form_kwargs={'request': request, 'application': application})
```

***forms.py***

```
class FirmPartnerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FirmPartner
        exclude = ['application']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FirmPartnerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('application', None):
            application = kwargs.get('application

            .....................
            .....................
```

***Error Traceback***

```
  File "/Users/name/projects/project_name/applications/views.py", line 462, in application_management
    form_kwargs={'request': request, 'application': application})
TypeError: modelformset_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form_kwargs'
```

So after `Daniel` said form_kwargs has been added in 1.9, i have upgraded to 1.9.9 and still i was getting the above error ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms) parameter is what you need.

```
modelformset_factory(FirmPartner, form=FirmPartnerForm, can_delete=True, extra=1,
                     form_kwargs={'request': request, 'application': application})
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks Daniel, I don't know why i din't get this thought, just debugging, debugging debugging huhhhhh

Comment: Daniel: oops ! this was the error `modelformset_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form_kwargs'`

Comment: What version of Django are you using? This argument was added in 1.9.

Comment: oh it was Django==1.8.2, are there any possibilities for achieving this in 1.8 ?

Comment: Daniel: Please see my edit above, i have upgraded django to 1.9.9 and still i was getting this error message